# How to make nested colors in one div background?

Tags: css, colors, background, html

How I can put multiple nested colors (or 2 colors precisely) to a div in css?
If it's possible to do that, how I can specify the nesting form, as percentage of each color, position, etc?

I mean the gradients, to make a background like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by nesting? Can you show an example of what effect you want to achieve?

Is there any reason why you can't use nested divs and assign a different background color to each one? Why do you want to have both colors on the same div?

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a 50/50 background if that's what you mean, using gradient, e.g.:

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(50%,#000000), color-stop(50%,#333));
```

Or for a full gradient, e.g.:

```
-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00b7ea), color-stop(100%,#000ed8));
```

Which is pretty straight forward, you just have to add the start and finish color. Also, I'm saving space above but you should of course use -o-linear-gradient, -ms-linear-gradient, linear-gradient as well if you want to be supported on all browsers).

There are also tools available to help you out:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: these are not nested or mixed colors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RGB colors in order to choose one specific color:

```
background-color:rgb(255,255,255)
```

and playing with the values.
you can also use color codes:

```
background-color:#FF0F00
```

That is how you can reach a specific color (which is combined from two different ones). I don't know of any ways to nest them.

If you would like to read more about the subject you can read about it here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colors.asp

Good luck :)